# Automator save POSIX path from folder action as a variable in shell script

Tags: macos, shell, unix, automator

I want to save POSIX path of the file(which triggers the folder action while being copied to that folder) as a  variable in the automator.
I have attempted but failed.
[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCQFw.png)

Comment: Do you mean a variable?  What have you tried?

Comment: Check the image that I have attached in the question. I have tried to do shell command to get the POSIX path of the file in "Demo" folder, but failed.

Comment: What else is in the workflow?  Getting a file such as from an **Ask for Finder Items** action and passing it to that shell script results in its POSIX path, which can then be passed to other actions, such as **Set Value of Variable**.